# Pandas chained methods to plot count of categories based on years

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1901,1901,1902,1902], 'Category': list('ABCC'), 'Shared': [1,1,2,2]})
```

I like to get the count of categories based on years.
So far I have done this:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Year','Category']).count().unstack()
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.droplevel()
new_df.reset_index().drop('Year',axis=1).sum().plot.bar()
```

This works good and gives the plot:
[image]

**Is there way to get the same results using chained commands?**

For example:

```
(df.groupby(['Year','Category'])
.count()
.unstack()
.droplevel()
.reset_index()
.drop('Year',axis=1)
.sum().plot.bar())
```

Comment: Do you need to use count (specifically non-nulls) or would size work? `df.groupby('Category').size().plot.bar()`

Comment: @ayhan without nans.

Comment: Then I would probably go with `df.groupby('Category')['Year'].count().plot.bar()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the very simple answer.

```
df['Category'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Also, thanks for Scott Boston for devising alternative solutions:

```
df['Category'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()
df.groupby('Category')['Shared'].count().plot.bar()
df.groupby(['Year','Category'])['Shared'].count().sum(level=1).plot.bar()
```

Comment: And, add sort_index to get the exact same output.  `df['Category'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()`

Comment: `df.groupby('Category')['Shared'].count().plot.bar()`

Comment: `df.groupby(['Year','Category'])['Shared'].count().sum(level=1).plot.bar()`